# Parse Json Response through Dictionary object

Tags: json, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api

I have Json response through Facebook API like this:

[image]

Now I want to parse this data so I can use within my game. For this purpose, I have written code up to this:

```
 public void OnChallengesButtonClick ()
 {
     SoundManager.Instance.PlayButtonClickSound ();

     FB.API ("/me/friends", HttpMethod.GET, RetrieveFacebookFriends);
 }

 public void RetrieveFacebookFriends (IGraphResult result)
 {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.Error)) {
         Debug.Log ("ERROR: " + result.Error);
         return;
     }

     IDictionary<string,object> friendsDict = result.ResultDictionary;

     Debug.Log ("raw: " + result.RawResult);
 }
```

So how to extract **name** and **ID** data from available Json response through Dictionary object?

Comment: I have received json information into Dictionary form, now I want to retrieve each information from response.

Comment: Question edited little bit too...

Comment: May this is duplicate of this [Getting Text from IResult Facebook SDK, 7.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250518/getting-text-from-iresult-facebook-sdk-7-2-0)

Comment: Look into the [JSON serializer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) in Unity. That's what I would use to go from raw JSON to an object in C# that you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is all I need: [JSON with Unity](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/Json)

```
friends = (List<object>)(((Dictionary<string, object>)friendsH) ["data"]);
if(friends.Count > 0) {
    var friendDict = ((Dictionary<string,object>)(friends[0]));
    var friend = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    friend["id"] = (string)friendDict["id"];
    friend["first_name"] = (string)friendDict["first_name"];
}
```

Before I can't able to find this post from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should create a class to serialize/deserialize an object:

```
class FBResponse
  FBDataResponse data;

class FBDataResponse
  string name;
  string id;
```

Take a look to my response here for more details (after "Final EDIT" part):
[Converting arrays of arrays to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193503/converting-arrays-of-arrays-to-json/51193771#51193771)

It should be easy to create those two class and use them to deserialize the FB response. Just remember that your variables will need to match the same name with the json response from Facebook (for example you cannot call data data1).

After you have the object it should be easy to do what you want with it... and with the object you should be able to get the json again.

PS. Unity default json serializer does not support Dictionary that's why you need to serialize two object. If you don't want that you should try to use a different library.